# Is there a monitor arm with purely sideways movement?

Tags: multiple-monitors, monitor-stand

I would like to have a VESA mount for my monitor to be able to dynamically move it from the left side on my desk to the middle in a straight line. Like it moves on a dolly (however, an arm would be better as it keeps the desk free).

I am really a fan of these pneumatic spring arms allowing for effortless movements. However, a typical arm would - due to its rotational joints - slide in an arc over my desk and collide with stuff on it

[image]

As the desk is directly in front of a wall with only a small gap in-between, the arm also cannot extend behind the desk during movement (which would allow for a straight line transition on the desk):

[image]

[image]

Comment: Seems like you would need to mount the monitor on some kind of rail if you want to have it slide side-to-side without "swinging" forward. Search for "slide" or "rail" instead of "arm".